# ¿Diccionarios en JAVA?

Tags: java, diccionarios

Quiero hacer un diccionario en `JAVA` como se hace en `python` y veo que no es lo mismo...

Busque un poco y creo que se puede hacer con `HashMap` pero aun asi me tira error:

> HashMap dicc = new HashMap(String, Int)(); --> no se
>   puede pero
>
> HashMap dicc = new HashMap(String, String)(); -> si se
>   puede

Entonces como hago para armar un diccionario facil donde almacene por ejemplo:
¿Nombres y nota de examen.. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

map.put("valor1", 15);
map.put("valor2", 20);
map.put("valor3", 1000);
map.put("valor4", 1500);
map.put("valor5", 2);

int valor1 = map.get("valor1");

// para saber el número más alto se debe recorrer el mapa
int valorMax = -1;

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    final int valorActual = entry.getValue();

    if (valorActual > valorMax)
        valorMax = valorActual;
}

System.out.println("Valor máximo: " + valorMax);
```

Puedes encontrar más información [aquí.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

Comment: perfectoo! solo tengo una duda. digamos que quiero decir luego de haber almacenado 20 alumonos con sus respectivas notas, cual fue la nota mas alta y por que alumno. sabes como es eso?

Comment: Tendrás que recorrer el map para saber el resultado más alto.

Answer (score 1):

Une equivalente de los [dictionarios en Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) en Java, sería un [**HashMap**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) en donde también puedes almacenar elementos definidos por llave (key) y valor (value).

En realidad esto se puede realizar:

> HashMap dicc = new HashMap(String, Int)(); --> no se puede

Solo depende de los tipos que definas para llave (key) y valor (value) que usará tu [**HashMap**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), en este caso lo definirías de esta forma:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

---

> ¿Como obtener el valor mayor almacenado en un HashMap?

Puedes usar varias opciones, por ejemplo:

```
    Map.Entry<String, Integer> maxEntry = null;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (maxEntry == null || entry.getValue().compareTo(maxEntry.getValue()) > 0) {
            maxEntry = entry;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("El valor más alto es = " + maxEntry.getValue());
```

Usando Java 8, puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
Object valorMaximo = Collections.max(map.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getValue();

System.out.println("El valor más alto es = " + valorMaximo.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

**HashMap** tiene la implementación de la forma (clave, valor) como por ejemplo:

```java
HashMap<k,v> //por lo tanto las puedes declarar de la siguiente forma

HashMap<Integer, String> test1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
HashMap<String, Integer> test2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
HashMap<String, Object> test3 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
//etc
```

más info y ejemplos [acá](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashmap-in-java-with-example/)